# Blazor Renderfragment based on condition

Tags: blazor

I have a table-pattern with a table inside a table several times in my code, so I thought I can outsource it into a template with RenderFragments like:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (TableItems != null)
    {
        @foreach (var tableItem in TableItems)
        {
            <tr>
                @TableRowTemplate(tableItem)
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="@Colspan">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            @if (SubTableHeader != null)
                            {
                                <tr>@SubTableHeader</tr>
                            }
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (SubTableItems != null && TableRowTemplate != null)
                            {

                                @foreach (var subTableItem in SubTableItems)
                                {
                                    <tr>@SubTableRowTemplate(subTableItem)</tr>

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                    @NotFoundMessage
                                </div>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</tbody>
```

However, the second table should only show up if a Property of tableItem is true. The name of the variable depends on the type and has to be accessed inside the foreach-loop:

```
        <TableWithSubTableTemplate Items="pets" TItem="Pet">
        <TableHeader>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableRowTemplate>
            <td>@pets.Name</td>
            <td>....</td>
        </TableRowTemplate>
        if(@pets.Active) // This doesn't work, because of the [design][1]
        {
            <SubTableHeader>
             .....
            </SubTableHeader>
            <SubTableRowTemplate>
             .....
            </SubTableRowTemplate>
         }
    </TableWithSubTableTemplate>
```

It is also not possible to add the parameter because passing parameters is only possible in the outter < TableWithSubTableTemplate >. What is the proper way to handle this?

.[1]: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10836

Comment: Why can't you push the condition check on pets.Active inside the child component?

Comment: You question needs to contain more detail.  There simply isn't enough information to give you an answer without making some wild guesses.  For example  `SubTableRowTemplate(subTableItem)` looks like a method that is passed `subTableItem` which I also can't see in the quoted code.  I'm guessing it's actually a  `RenderFragment`, but without seeing it declared I don't know.